# prove this circles question involving polar

Tags: analytic-geometry, circles

Through a fixed point O are drawn straight lines OPQ and ORS to meet a circle in P and Q, and R and S. Prove that the locus of the point of intersection of PR and QS, as also that of the point of intersection of PR and QS, is the polar of O with respect to the circle.

Comment: Reference http://paulscottinfo.ipage.com/PLC/8/8.html#anchor3

Comment: I don't understand how the question is solved, I also don't understand how the harmonic conjugate answers my question. Please explain in detail

Comment: You probably need to start from the first chapter - "inversion points", Then the second - "pole and polar". All of these are clearly shown in that website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have converted the problem into oblique coordinates and eliminated $x_1$, $x_2$, $y_1$ and $y_2$. Then I found polar with respect to the circle and then proved both are same[image: the following picture explains everything]